# Remove a comma from the end of a word in a TextBox

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to remove a comma from the end of a name in a text box using VBA. With this problem I first had to sort a name into the two text boxes by means of clicking a command button. The problem is that the user may enter the name as `FirstName, LastName` OR `FirstName (single space) LastName`.  Now I am stuck trying to remove the comma. I have had success with removing a specific number or letter, but removing the comma will not work. The message I get is *syntax error*. My code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LNFN As String
Dim LastName As String
Dim FirstName As String
LNFN = TextBox4.Text
FirstName = Split(LNFN)(1)
LastName = Split(LNFN)(0)
TextBox2.Text = FirstName
TextBox3.Text = LastName
TextBox2 = TextBox2.Value
 If Right(TestBox2, 1) = “,” Then
  TempString = Left(TextBox2, Len(TextBox2) - 1)
 End If
TextBox2.Text = TempString
End Sub
```

Comment: No, I just have regular quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
LNFN = Replace(TextBox4.Text, ",", "")
```

Then you will not need any of the other code that was dealing with the comma.

Comment: @ExcelHero, try using vbNullString instead of "" it avoids coding mishaps ?